# No Language: Travis CI

Tags: travis-ci

How can is specify: language: none in .travis.yml?
I don't specify a language, and get Ruby by default.
i have no Ruby. I'm using C, C++, Ocaml, Python, and Felix.
The build script is just "make".

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?

Answer (score 12):

You can set `language: minimal` or `language: generic` which are not language specific.

From the [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/minimal-and-generic/):

`minimal` has some essential CI tools and Python:

- version control tools
- essential build tools such as gcc and make
- network tools such as curl and essential
- Docker
- python

`generic` extends `minimal` and additionally includes:

- databases and services
- go
- jvm
- node_js
- php
- ruby

Answer (score 3):

Start with setting `language: c`

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/

https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/c

You might run into problems as per https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4090